# Why is my bootstrap input not filling the space?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="schedule landingDetail container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background: red;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background: green;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-md-12" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My col-md-6's seem to be working correctly, but my inputs are not filling up the available space.  It looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Twitter Bootstrap adds padding to the column grid classes, you will need to set the padding to 0 to cover the entire width.

```css
.schedule .form-group .col-md-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="schedule landingDetail container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background: red;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background: green;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm col-md-12" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```